# Concatenating numpy arrays vertically and horizontally

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

I have a numpy multidimensional array array with the following format:

```
a  = [[1,2],
      [8,9]]
```

Then I want to add a list with 3 values (e.g. `[4,5,6]` at the end horizontally and vertically with the following result:

```
a = [[1,2,4],
     [8,9,5],
     [4,5,6]]
```

Do I need to combine row_stack and column_stack somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way using `hstack` and `vstack`:

```
>>> a  = [[1,2],
...       [8,9]]
>>> x = np.array([4, 5, 6])

>>> b = np.vstack((a, x[:-1]))
>>> print np.hstack((b, x[:, None]))
[[1 2 4]
 [8 9 5]
 [4 5 6]]
```

You can combine this into one line:

```
>>> print np.hstack((np.vstack((a, x[:-1])), x[:, None]))
[[1 2 4]
 [8 9 5]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether there's a better way (i.e. a one-liner), but you could just do this:

```
z = np.zeros((3,3))
z[:2,:2] = a
z[:,2] = z[2,:] = array([4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: This only works if you know how large the final product will be, I guess. I need to be able to use a for loop to keep expanding the matrix.

Comment: @Chielt Just as a note extending arrays in this way is extremely slow since you have to copy the entire array in memory every time. It would likely be better to simply know the maximum possible size fill it iteratively using this technique, and then trim it.

Comment: @Ophion, The problem being that the array is a distance matrix between different objects. As new objects are added, the distance between the new object (and every existing object) is calculated and stored. As the relationship is bi-directional, the values need to be stored vertically and horizontally. As the number of objects that will be added is unknown, the maximum possible size is effectively infinite.

Comment: @Chielt Don't know how often you have to extend the array, or how costy it really is, but you could do it in a similar way e.g. Java's ArrayList does it (unless I'm mistaken): Start with some small size, and when it gets too big, double the size.

Comment: That sounds like a decent solution @tobias_k. However, the project I am doing is for a university course where we have to experiment with scrapers/crawlers. Luckily performance lies outside the scope of the assignment :) Thanks for the input though :)